# Ubuntu 14.04 Shuts Down Improperly

Tags: shutdown

Only 2 or 3 dots (out of five) light up before the system shuts down. Applications such as Firefox are not closed properly, as I find out upon next start (asks to recover previous session). I suspect this behaviour can damage my harddisk.

I am a new user, with no knowledge on Ubuntu whatsoever, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is effect of command "sudo poweroff" in terminal ?

Comment: ..after closing anything important that is open

Comment: Normal shutdown pursues. I think I figured it out, thanks..

Answer (score 2):

That animation is not a loading one, so there is no relationship between how many dots are light up and the status of any action (weather is starting or stopping Ubuntu).

The behaviour of Firefox that you describe doesn't imply that Ubuntu didn't shut down correctly. It can mean that Ubuntu killed (is the term used) Firefox without letting it to do a proper shutdown (just FF shutdown, not Ubuntu).

Firefox recover feature is explained [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-previous-session).

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this in Firefox's settings:

> [image: When Firefox starts: Show my home page]

If you go to Firefox's settings, you can change this behaviour by clicking the above box and changing it to:

> When Firefox starts: Show my windows and tabs from last time

If you have the Firefox's standard home page (not Ubuntu's, use `about:home` as the home page), it may also show a button saying 'restore previous session'.

Either that or you are logged in you guest account - when you login you should see ((after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (in Nautilus GNOME/Unity's file manager) to show the hidden files beginning with a `.`)* `~/.mozilla` and other directories in your home directory.

The thing you see on start and shutdown is the plymouth boot screen - it does not show the progress of what is happening, it just acts as a pretty cover for the text output 'behind' it (press a key and it probably will show loads of text along the line of 'module loaded')

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time, I do feel assured now.